# d2d1debug3.dll!DebugRenderTarget::EndDraw Access violation

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, access-violation, direct2d

This question is similar to : [Intermittent Access Violation ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489485/intermittent-access-violation-id2d1rendertargetenddraw) but I've done all that was suggested in that question and is still no where near the solution.

My application(Windows Store Application) dies throws memory access violation exception sometimes(not all the time, usually after few minutes of heavy use, and only in Win10 devices) when running the 1D2DRenderTarget::EndDraw. According to the dump file, it says: "The thread tried to read from or write to  a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."

There are few variants, but it breaks down to access violation while doing the EndDraw call. Here are disassembles and call stacks:

```
d3d10warp.dll!UMDevice::DestroyResource(struct D3D10DDI_HDEVICE,struct D3D10DDI_HRESOURCE)  Unknown
d3d11.dll!NDXGI::CDeviceChild<IDXGIResource1,IDXGISwapChainInternal>::FinalRelease()    Unknown
d3d11.dll!CUseCountedObject<NOutermost::CDeviceChild>::UCDestroy()  Unknown
d3d11.dll!CUseCountedObject<NOutermost::CDeviceChild>::UCReleaseUse()   Unknown
d3d11.dll!NDXGI::CDeviceChild<IDXGISurface,IUnknown>::FinalRelease()    Unknown
d3d11.dll!CUseCountedObject<NOutermost::CDeviceChild>::UCDestroy()  Unknown
d3d11.dll!CDevCtxInterface::CDevCtxInterface<CContext>()    Unknown
d3d11.dll!CContext::TID3D11DeviceContext_SetShaderResources_Amortized<0,4>()    Unknown
d2d1.dll!CD3DDeviceLevel1::ProcessDeferredOperations()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::FlushQueuedOperations()    Unknown
d2d1.dll!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::EndProcessBatch()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::ProcessBatch() Unknown
d2d1.dll!CBatchSerializer::FlushInternal()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!CBatchSerializer::Flush()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!DrawingContext::FlushBatch()   Unknown
d2d1.dll!DrawingContext::EndDraw()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!D2DDeviceContextBase<ID2D1RenderTarget,ID2D1DeviceContext3,ID2D1DeviceContext3>::EndDraw() Unknown
d2d1debug3.dll!DebugRenderTarget::EndDraw(class DebugLayer &,struct ID2D1RenderTarget *,unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)  Unknown
d2d1debug3.dll!DebugRenderTargetGenerated<struct ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget>::EndDraw(unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)   Unknown
OZDebugApp_wrt_2013.exe!OZXCanvasD2D::~OZXCanvasD2D() Line 203  C++
```

Disassembly:

```
679F0EC1  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebx+4]  
679F0EC4  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],eax  
679F0EC7  jmp         UMDevice::DestroyResource+1CAh (679F0E6Ah)  
679F0EC9  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi+220h]  
679F0ECF  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+3Ch]  
679F0ED2  test        eax,eax  
679F0ED4  je          UMDevice::DestroyResource+135h (679F0DD5h)  
679F0EDA  cmp         eax,0FFBADBADh  
679F0EDF  je          UMDevice::DestroyResource+135h (679F0DD5h)  
679F0EE5  mov         cl,byte ptr ds:[67B58280h]  
>> 679F0EEB  movzx       eax,byte ptr [eax]  
679F0EEE  add         ecx,eax  
679F0EF0  mov         byte ptr ds:[67B58280h],cl  
679F0EF6  jmp         UMDevice::DestroyResource+135h (679F0DD5h)  
679F0EFB  push        1
```

This is another variant

```
msvcrt.dll!__VEC_memcpy()  Unknown
msvcrt.dll!__VEC_memcpy()  Unknown
d2d1.dll!DrawingContext::EndDraw()  Unknown
D2D1Debug3.dll!DebugRenderTarget::EndDraw(class DebugLayer &,struct ID2D1RenderTarget *,unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)  Unknown
D2D1Debug3.dll!DebugRenderTargetGenerated<struct ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget>::EndDraw(unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)   Unknown
OZDebugApp_wrt_2013.exe!OZXCanvasD2D::~OZXCanvasD2D() Line 203  C++
```

Disassembly:

```
76C7A3A7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],esi  
76C7A3AA  mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
76C7A3AD  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
76C7A3B0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+10h]  
76C7A3B3  shr         ecx,7  
76C7A3B6  jmp         __VEC_memcpy+108h (76C7A3BEh)  
76C7A3B8  lea         ebx,[ebx]  
>> 76C7A3BE  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [esi]  
76C7A3C2  movdqa      xmm1,xmmword ptr [esi+10h]  
76C7A3C7  movdqa      xmm2,xmmword ptr [esi+20h]  
76C7A3CC  movdqa      xmm3,xmmword ptr [esi+30h]  
76C7A3D1  movdqa      xmmword ptr [edi],xmm0  
76C7A3D5  movdqa      xmmword ptr [edi+10h],xmm1  
76C7A3DA  movdqa      xmmword ptr [edi+20h],xmm2  
76C7A3DF  movdqa      xmmword ptr [edi+30h],xmm3
```

Things I've tried:

1. I checked multithreading. My application uses one 1D2D factory with multithread property with multiple render targets so drawings should be interleaved by default. On top of that, I tried to add locks so that each BeginDraw, EndDraw, render target creations, and DXGI related stuffs are in critical section.
2. Ran with debug layer enabled, both with DirectX control panel and code.
3. Generated the crash dump file but using it seems to be exactly the same with just debugging the remote machine?
4. Implemented a logger to generate composition/drawing calls and arguments for each render target. Each run generated around 40mb of logs. I checked the render targets that crashed and their drawings are identical to some of the earlier drawings ie) I honestly can't see what's going wrong at drawing level.

None of the above worked, I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I didn't set critical section for one instance of CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget. Running D2Dfactory in multithread property does interleave all Direct2D calls, but it doesn't work on WIC, DXGI, or other D3D calls. I had to use:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Multithread> d2DMultithread;
        d2dFactory.As(&d2DMultithread);
        d2DMultithread->Enter();
        HRESULT targetCreationResult =  d2dFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(m_wicBitmap.Get(), &prop, &target);
        d2DMultithread->Leave();
```

Done the same for other render target creation and Begin/EndDraw. I noticed the above by looking at the thread view in debug.